# Why does Google Drive fileLastModified() not give the correct time for Form submission?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-forms

The following Google Apps Script bound to the spreadsheet that also receives a Form's responses, but the file last modified date "mod" does not change when a form response is received, why?

```
function myFunction() {
     var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
     SpreadsheetApp.flush()
     var id = ss.getId();
     var file = DriveApp.getFileById(id);
     var mod = file.getLastUpdated();
     var created = file.getDateCreated();
     Logger.log('mod: %s, created: %s',mod,created);
  }

Results:  
mod: Wed Aug 09 16:47:44 GMT-07:00 2023, created: Wed Aug 09 16:06:07 GMT-07:00 2023 (before)
8/9/2023 16:50:30 Option 2 (this is the form response)
mod: Wed Aug 09 16:47:44 GMT-07:00 2023, created: Wed Aug 09 16:06:07 GMT-07:00 2023 (after)
```

I do not understand why the form response is not seen by this script.
File> Document Details reports file modified 4:50, correct.
I want my script to only read the responses if something new has been submitted, but fileLastModified() lets submissions arrive undetected.

Of course opening the file and getLastRow() works fine, new submissions increase the number of rows.
Anybody know what is wrong here?  Thanks.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue and your goal? About `I want my script to only read the responses if something new has been submitted`, how about using OnSubmit trigger? But, I cannot know your goal. I apologize for this. So, first, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: I'm sorry but I also don't understand exactly what you are trying to do with file mod/creation dates. OTOH, `I want my script to only read the responses if something new has been submitted` The meaning of "something new" is vague and ambiguous but perhaps you mean that you only want your script to execute when a form submission is received. In which case, are you familiar with [triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) and specifically `onFormSubmit()` [ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit)

Comment: I suspect it has something to do with avoiding DDOS attacks.  It's the same kind of reasoning why onEdit() does not respond to changes from other scripts or formulas.

Comment: Regarding your title question, i believe that could be related to a topic escalated to (and still waiting for response from) Google: https://support.google.com/docs/thread/227290739.
As for the post question, as @Tedinoz suggests, you can use an "On form submit" trigger.